# "Unexpected _data T_String" in Blade, Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-4

I was following along with Jeffrey Ways laracasts on his website and was really learning but unfortunately I made an error somewhere and I don't know where that is. I am receiving the following error.

```
https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

syntax error, unexpected '__data' (T_STRING)

<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<h1>All Users</h1>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<li><?php echo link_to("/users/{$user->username}", $user->username); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>;
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.default, array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

I'm not quite sure why I am getting this issue. Can someone explain it to me please so I can understand?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a single quote after `layouts.default`. Please refer to the syntax highlighting in your question for further reference.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you missed a single quote on the last line. Try this:

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>
<h1>All Users</h1>
<?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
<li><?php echo link_to("/users/{$user->username}", $user->username); ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>;
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>
<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.default', array_except(get_defined_vars(), array('__data', '__path')))->render(); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, in my case i was missing a single quote, as well. ☺

Comment: That single quote has just caused me 30 freaking minutes!

Comment: Thank you ! solved my problem too ! it was actually an error when  using the extend function in laravel blade I made @extends('layouts.agency.master) instead of @extends('layouts.agency.master')

Comment: strangely, phpstorm doesn't complain about the missing semicolon :(

Comment: Thanks for the tip exactly what I had.

Comment: lol, that's a good catch. missing single quote, as well